# jQuery Mobile load new data only

Tags: javascript, jquery, refresh, settimeout, jquery-mobile-listview

I'm working on this project for learning purposes. The tasks for now are very simple:

1. Populate data from **DB** using `$.getJSON`.
2. Check every `'n'` seconds for new data and `append` it to the list.
3. Notify user about new data changes.

Here is the example of where I got so far: ( [**JSBin**](http://jsbin.com/wicaba/5/edit) **/Don't forget to run js**)
All the issues will be visible when running the example.

Here is the **JS** code that i have:

```
$(document).bind('pageinit', function(){

    var $myList = $( "#myList" );
    var newItems = [];

  function loadList(){  
  $.getJSON("http://jsbin.com/vayeni/2.js",function(data){

   $.each(data, function( index, value ) {

     newItems.push( "<li><a>" + value.airline + "</a></li>" );
           if(data>newItems){
            alert('New Entry');
            data=newItems;
      }
   });
        $myList.append( newItems.join( "" ) );
        $myList.listview( "refresh" );
        setTimeout(loadList,1000);
  });
  }
    loadList();
});
```

**Thanks for your help !**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data comparison is not correct.

You are comapring this:

```
<li><a>JetBlue</a></li>
<li><a>Continental</a></li>
...
```

to this:

```
  {
    "id": "1",
    "airline": "JetBlue",
    "number": "222",
    "people": "3",
    "time": "12:20"
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "airline": "Continental",
    "number": "222",
    "people": "5",
    "time": "23:21"
  },
```

There will be always inequality.

You should use another approach. For example, if the `id` field from your JSON array is an unique one you can attach it to each item from the unordered list as an `id` attribute. For example:

```
newItems.push( "<li id=\"" + value.id + "\"><a>" + value.airline + "</a></li>" );
```

This way, at each iteration you can check if the incomming JSON item already exists into your list and add it when there is no match. Eg:

```
if (!$myList.find('#' + value.id).length) {
  newItems.push( "<li id=\" + value.id + \"><a>" + value.airline + "</a></li>" );
}
```

Finally, you can append the `newItems` contents directly if there are items inside:

```
if (newItems.length > 0) {
  $myList.append( newItems.join( "" ) );  
}
```

Here is the edited snippet: [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/joxeferivo/1/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: Good but seems like `setTimeout(loadList,1000);` still doesn't load new data. I added new data in my `json` file expecting that it will notify me but, no luck. What could be the reason of that ?

Comment: I've just tested it again and it seems that everything is ok. You are not forgetting to change the new data ids to unique ones, right ?

Comment: Yes, new data with unique id. I tried it in JSbin as well as in IntelXDK.

Comment: Please, provide the two JSBin links you are trying - the script and the json.

Comment: I tested it on `local` and it worked. Awesome :) What if i want to get this to a more sophisticated level? To be able to notify of any changes to any of the `data.field`. For example: `{"id":"9","name":"Boris"}` changed to `{"id":"9","name":"Peter"}` ?

Comment: What do you mean with `local` and `remotely` ? Here is an example: [script side](http://jsbin.com/hedaroxewe/1/edit) and the [data side](http://jsbin.com/rahohubiro/1/edit). If you add another item to the data with a different ID, the script will "catch" it and append it to the list. Keep in mind that if you change something in a JSBin snippet, its URL will change. In your case the data/json URL will change and you will have to update it into the $.getJSON function.

Comment: About your second question- _"To be able to notify of any changes to any of the data.field"_, obviously the script should be changed, but I think this should be a topic of a new answer.

Comment: Agree. Thank you again, you helped me a lot. Is there a way to notify you about my new questions? I'd like to address my questions to you, of course if that's not a problem.